# is going to be accessible

Tags: future-time, time-words

a. His new single should be accessible online sometime soon.

b. His new single should already be accessible online sometime soon.

===================

c. His new single is going to be accessible online sometime soon.

d. His new single is already going to be accessible online sometime soon.

Are all of the above sentences grammatically correct?

Are they idiomatic?

I think the 'already' versions might sound strange. The idea is that one wouldn't expect the single to be accessible online at such an early date. The fact that the single will be accessible online soon is surprising.

Answer (score 2):

(b) don't make sense. (d) is correct but its "already" part is unwanted - it may be used if you want to give a impression of "everything is going well, *project* is moving" or in an event when you are asked "Will the single go online?" or "Will the single go online any time soon?".

"Should already be accessible" means "you should be able to access it *now*".

(a) is the best version. (c) is grammatically correct, but sounds like informal conversation. I would expect an 'official' announcement to read *will be accessible.*